# cant close last opened file

Tags: python, csv, parsing

Hello if i have following code:

```
n = len([name for name in os.listdir(DIR) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(DIR, name))])
for i in range(0, n):
    dat_file = r'C1/C10000' + str(i).zfill(2) + '.dat'
    csv_file = r'C1_conv/C10000' + str(i).zfill(2) + '.csv'
    in_dat = csv.reader(open(dat_file, 'rb'), delimiter = '\t')
    out_csv = csv.writer(open(csv_file, 'wb'))
    out_csv.writerows(in_dat)
```

The problem i have is, that the last file stays opened.
I tried to close it with in_dat.close()...., but have read that its not possible because it is a parser.

I have read about the 'with' function, but don't know how to put this in.
Could someone show me the proper code, please?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to track opened file in a separate variable, and close it after finishing write operation. A better convention is to use `with open(fname)` syntax, which close file for you.

You may consult following code snippet to understand things in better way:

```
with open(infile, 'w') as datfile, open(outfile, 'w') as csvfile:
       do_something()
```